# Difficulty with variables in a class

Tags: python, class

I recently started using Python a couple of days ago, and have since decided to build a small text adventure game. After reading around on the forums, I took to containing as much information as possible within classes so that things were kept clear and concise.

My problem is that the variables I am storing within my classes are being executed regardless of their relative "if" statement in my "changeTo" function. Here for example, the program immediately "changes to" "p1SelectClass" without giving the user the chance to access the main menu. Here is the relevant code:

```
import time

from random import randrange

def changeTo(part):

    print(part.desc)

    time.sleep(1)

    print(part.op1)
    print(part.op2)
    print(part.op3)
    print(part.op4)
    print(part.op5)
    print("")
    print(part.extra)

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == "1":
    part.exeOne

    if choice == "2":
    part.exeTwo

    if choice == "3":
    part.exeThree

    if choice == "4":
    part.exeFour

    if choice == "5":
    part.exeFive

tips = ["Enter 'funcHelp()' at any time for a list of commands", "The command
'checkInv()' will list all of your inventory items", "Entering 'vers()' will list
current version information", "The command 'skillGet()' will list each level in its
respective skill", "Want to check your hit points? Try 'player.hp'"]

randomTip = randrange(0, (len(tips)))

class player:

    hp = (100)
    inventory = [ "100 gold" ] 
    skills = [0, 0, 0, 0] #strength, endurance, dexterity, wisdom

class p1SelectClass:

    desc = ("Welcome to Anguem, a fully fledged Python adventure game. Please select
    Of the four major classes below\n")

    op1 = ("Knight: 6 STR, 9 END, 4 DEX, 5 WIS")
    op2 = ("Barbarian: 9 STR, 6 END, 5 DEX, 4 WIS")
    op3 = ("Ranger: 6 STR, 4 END, 9 DEX, 5 WIS")
    op4 = ("Wizard: 4 STR, 5 END, 6 DEX, 9 WIS")
    op5 = ("")

    extra = ("")

    #execute

class p0MainMenu:

    desc = ("Would you like to...")

    op1 = ("1. Start a new game")
    op2 = ("2. Load game")
    op3 = ("3. Quit game")
    op4 = ("")
    op5 = ("")

    extra = ("Tips of the play: " + tips[randomTip])

    exeOne = changeTo(p1SelectClass)
    exeTwo = ("Loading and saving is currently unsupported in Anguem 0.2")
    exeThree = ("quit goes here") #placeholder
    exeFour = ("Please select a valid option")
    exeFive = ("Please select a valid option")

print("Hello user, welcome to Anguem 0.2\n")

time.sleep(2)

changeTo(p0MainMenu)
```

This is probably riddles with rookie errors, but does anyone have any advice on how to get this working properly?

Comment: Your indentation is not correct. This is **imperative** to have correct in python

Comment: You seem to be treating classes as functions that are run immediately. I suggest finding and reading a Python tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You need indentations. New lines, indentations, tabs, etc are very important in Python.

```
if choice == "1":
    part.exeOne
elif choice == "2":
    part.exeTwo
elif choice == "3":
    part.exeThree
elif choice == "4":
    part.exeFour
elif choice == "5":
    part.exeFive
else:
    # default stuff
```

Comment: Still doesn't make sense, as `exeOne` etc just seem to be strings - not at all clear what the OP wants to do with them. Perhaps print?

Comment: @DanielRoseman I'm not really sure what OP wants to do with the rest of the code. To be honest I didn't really look at much of what they are doing in their classes because those are very strangely written. I was just answering the "why do my if statements not work" question.

Comment: I lost the indentation when pasting in the answer box, in the same way, so I think that was a bug in Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You have very basic errors ("rookie", indeed). I advise you to read a bit more about classes in Python before you continue.

With that said, I tried to make as few changes as possible, keeping what (I think) you intended to do. I hope this helps you to advance.

```
import time

from random import randrange

def changeTo(part):

    print(part.desc)

    time.sleep(1)

    print(part.op1)
    print(part.op2)
    print(part.op3)
    print(part.op4)
    print(part.op5)
    print("")
    print(part.extra)

    choice = input("> ")

    if choice == 1:    # input returns an integer if you type an integer
        part.exeOne()  # to execute a function, you need the parentheses

    if choice == 2:
        part.exeTwo()

    if choice == 3:
        part.exeThree()

    if choice == 4:
        part.exeFour()

    if choice == 5:
        part.exeFive()

tips = ["Enter 'funcHelp()' at any time for a list of commands", "The command 'checkInv()' will list all of your inventory items", "Entering 'vers()' will list current version information", "The command 'skillGet()' will list each level in its respective skill", "Want to check your hit points? Try 'player.hp'"] 

randomTip = randrange(0, (len(tips)))

class player:

    hp = (100)
    inventory = [ "100 gold" ] 
    skills = [0, 0, 0, 0] #strength, endurance, dexterity, wisdom

class p1SelectClass:
  def __init__(self):  # I am changing these from class variables to instance variables
                       # mostly to show you how it's done
                       # __init__() is called when you create a p1SelectClass instance
    self.desc = ("Welcome to Anguem, a fully fledged Python adventure game. Please select Of the four major classes below\n") # instance variables need to be addressed with "self."

    self.op1 = ("Knight: 6 STR, 9 END, 4 DEX, 5 WIS")
    self.op2 = ("Barbarian: 9 STR, 6 END, 5 DEX, 4 WIS")
    self.op3 = ("Ranger: 6 STR, 4 END, 9 DEX, 5 WIS")
    self.op4 = ("Wizard: 4 STR, 5 END, 6 DEX, 9 WIS")
    self.op5 = ("")

    self.extra = ("")

    #execute

def pp(x): # I defined this function to be able to call "print" from an expression
    print x

class p0MainMenu:
  def __init__(self):
    self.desc = ("Would you like to...")

    self.op1 = ("1. Start a new game")
    self.op2 = ("2. Load game")
    self.op3 = ("3. Quit game")
    self.op4 = ("")
    self.op5 = ("")

    self.extra = ("Tips of the play: " + tips[randomTip])

    # If you intend to run this later, then the variable must be executable.
    # In this case, I created a lambda (an unnamed function)
    # The proper way would be to define a method.
    #
    # This was the first error that you caught: exeOne = changeTo(p1SelectClass)
    # runs changeTo immediately, it will not wait until exeOne is "called".
    self.exeOne = lambda: changeTo(p1SelectClass())
    self.exeTwo = lambda: pp("Loading and saving is currently unsupported in Anguem 0.2")
    self.exeThree = lambda: pp("quit goes here") #placeholder
    self.exeFour = lambda: pp("Please select a valid option")
    self.exeFive = lambda: pp("Please select a valid option")

print("Hello user, welcome to Anguem 0.2\n")

time.sleep(2)

# p0MainMenu is the class, p0MainMenu() is a new instance of the class
changeTo(p0MainMenu())
```

Comment: Thanks for going through this! I'll make sure to take a look into some of your amendments more thoroughly